# How to run a ruby on rails web application locally in Windows (Xampp) in Production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My web application runs in Windows with Xampp server. Now in development mode. I want to try production mode.

I stopped server and restarted again.

I issued command

```
$> rails s -e production (for starting)
```

I get error " We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information." in browser screen.

In my database.yml, I do have both development and production databases available (mysql).

Please let me know how to proceed here. Thanks.

My Git bash output:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.3 application starting in production
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.1 (ruby 2.5.5-p157), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: production
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

Observation: Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000 (But the error described pops up in browser) when I point to localhost:3000

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.
>
> If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

Comment: What does your server console show when you get the "We're sorry..." message in your browser?

Comment: @jvillian, it shows:Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error). Then it showed : Navigated to http://localhost:3000/

Comment: Add the whole stack trace to your question.